# Not able to access detail information from Api using React Router not rendering on the page

Tags: reactjs, match, react-router-dom

I am building a small React Routing application to get a better idea as to how it work.  My App.js looks like this with the basic routing:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './Nav';
import About from './About';
import Shop from './Shop';
import CountryDetail from './CountryDetail'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/shop" exact component={Shop} />
          <Route path="/shop/:name" component={CountryDetail} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
  </div>
);
```

Now the Shop component a list of countries from the api which is in the code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function Shop() {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  },[])

  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');
    const countries = await data.json();
    console.log(countries);
    setCountries(countries);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {countries.map(country => (
        <div>
          <Link to={`shop/${country.name}`}>
            <h1 key={country.alpha2Code}>
              {country.name}
            </h1>
          </Link>
          <p>Popluation {country.population}</p>
          <p> Region {country.region}</p>
          <p>Capital {country.capital}</p>
        </div>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Shop;
```

Now what I want to do is render more information about the country when I click on it. So I have created another component called CountryDetail:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';


function CountryDetail( { match } ) {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItem();
    console.log(match)
  },[])

  const [country, setCountry] = useState([])

  const fetchItem = async ()=> {
    const fetchCountry = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${match.params.name}`);
    const country = await fetchCountry.json();
    setCountry(country);
    console.log(country);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Name {country.name}</h1>
      <p>Native Name{country.nativeName}</p>
      <p>Region {country.region}</p>
      <p>Languages {country.languages}</p>
      <h1>This Country</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CountryDetail;
```

The problem I am having is that it is not rendering anything on the CountryDetail page.  I am sure I have hit the api correctly but not sure if I am getting the data correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when you say not rendering, is it not logging out `console.log(match)` in your effect?

Comment: What I want to do is reveal more information when click on the country name in shop.

Comment: In `CountryDetail `, is `country` an array or an object?

Comment: this is the url for the Api ```https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/Albania``` obviously Albania is going to be passed in.  It is an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:** The returned JSON is an array but your JSX assumes it is an object.

**Solution:** You should extract the 0th element from the JSON array. Surround in a try/catch in case of error, and correctly render the response.

*Note:* the languages is also an array, so that needs to be mapped

```
function CountryDetail({ match }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItem();
    console.log(match);
  }, []);

  const [country, setCountry] = useState(null);

  const fetchItem = async () => {
    try {
      const fetchCountry = await fetch(
        `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${match.params.name}`
      );
      const country = await fetchCountry.json();
      setCountry(country[0]);
      console.log(country[0]);
    } catch {
      // leave state alone or set some error state, etc...
    }
  };

  return (
    country && (
      <div>
        <h1>Name {country.name}</h1>
        <p>Native Name{country.nativeName}</p>
        <p>Region {country.region}</p>
        <p>Languages {country.languages.map(({ name }) => name).join(", ")}</p>
        <h1>This Country</h1>
      </div>
    )
  );
}
```

[image: Edit affectionate-merkle-74weu]

Comment: could I have done something like this ```{country.map(town => (
      
      <div>
       
        <h1 key={town.alpha2Code}>{town.name}</h1>
        <p>Native Name{town.nativeName}</p>
        <p>Region {town.region}</p>
        <p>Languages {town.languages}</p>``` ?

Comment: @AltBrian Sorry, I totally misread your question, yes, if *your* initial state is an empty array you could map the single element, when it exists. But as I pointed out in my previous comment, it's a little bit more overhead to iterate over the array and invoke the callback. Since presumably only 0 or 1 countries can ever match the query, IMO it makes more sense to just extract what you need to store in state.

Answer (score 0):

As you said it yourself, the response is an array (with a single country object in it), but you are using it as if it would be an object.

So, instead of:

```
const country = await fetchCountry.json();
setCountry(country);
```

It should be:

```
const countries = await fetchCountry.json();
setCountry(countries[0]);
```

Comment: unfortunately I got the following error ```Unhandled Rejection (Error): Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {iso639_1, iso639_2, name, nativeName}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in p (at CountryDetail.jsx:28)
    in div (at CountryDetail.jsx:24)
    in CountryDetail (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:15)
    in Switch (at App.js:14)
    in div (at App.js:12)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)```

Comment: That's because `country.languages` is an array, and React doesn't know what to do with that. Remove that line (or render it differently), and it will work.